# Исключить файлы с тестами из сборки webpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, jest

подскажите как исключить из сборки вебпака файлы с тестами .test.ts, .test.tsx. Я специально в файле с тестом делаю ошибку типо const str: string = 123; И запускаю npm run build. Сборка не проходит так как eslint и ts ругается на это. При исключении из сборки получается, сборка должна собраться даже с такой ошибкой.